# React app not receiving res.data (JSON) from Express server although Postman does

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-ec2

When sending POST or GET requests to our Express server which is being served through PM2 on EC2, Postman receives the full response including JSON data however our front end React app (both locally and deployed through CF) only receives the response status code and message and has the data variable as a blank string. The React app is using axios for these calls.

I've spent quite a bit of time with AWS support but we've concluded that it isn't an issue with EC2 or CF.

I've also gone over this a lot with my coworkers and we think it might be an async issue but we're stumped.

This is the client-side call:

```
export function signIn (data) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(addSignInStatus('PENDING'))
    axios.post(`${config.production_url}/api/user/login`, data)
      .then(res => {
        return dispatch(addSignIn(res.data))
      }).catch(err => {
        dispatch(addError(err))
        return dispatch(addSignInStatus('ERROR'))
      })
  }
}
```

And this is the server-side response:

```
export function login(req,res){
  let username = ''
  let password = ''
  if(req.body.username && req.body.password){
    username = req.body.username;
    password = req.body.password;
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({
      message:"Error logging In",
      error: "No username or password specified"
    });
    return;
  }
  _user.login(username,password).then(data=>{
    res.status(200).json(data)
  })
  .catch(error=>{
      res.status(400).json({message:"Error Signing in User",error:error});
  });
}
```

In the React app, the server responds with the proper status code and message, but res.data is returned as a blank string and in Firefox this error is thrown:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The server should be responding with a JSON object similar to this:

```
{
    "message": "Sign-in Successful",
    "user": {
        "skills": [],
        "social": [],
        "wallets": [],
        "followers": [],
        "following": [],
        "groupsOwned": [],
        "groupsJoined": [],
        "starred": [],
        "pinned": [],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

and it does when the request is sent through Postman.

Edit:

The server does accept cross origin requests:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Edit 2 SOLUTION:

Turns out it was an issue with the npm library "compression"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're making cross-domain requests that are failing. Browsers block cross-domain requests by default. The concept of cross-domain requests doesn't apply to Postman, because your client (Postman) is running with all the network permissions of your OS, instead of being confined inside of a browser.

Check your "Network" tab in your browser's developer tools. If your requests are cross-domain, the browser will precede them with an OPTIONS request. This is known as a "preflight request".

At that point, if your server expects cross-domain traffic, it is supposed to respond with a set of headers authorizing cross-browser requests. If it does, the browser will be reassured that no one is doing anything shady, and it will proceed to make the POST request that's in your code.

If your server isn't expecting cross-domain traffic, it will not respond with these headers. The browser will then, according to its security model, block the POST request that you wrote in your code. It will look something like the blank request that you're describing.

Here's everything you need to know to implement CORS on your server:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I forgot to mention that the server does accept requests from all origins:

`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");` Is this all correct?

Comment: From what I understand, the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in the OPTIONS request is supposed to contain the full list of the headers that might be sent in the POST request. So in my code I have `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control")`. You might need to look at all of the headers that the browser sends with your POST request and add them to the list.

Comment: I also have code that returns a blank response body (and skips the rest of the code that the request is supposed to run) `if (req.method === 'OPTIONS')`. Whether I did this as an optimization, or because it was actually necessary for the code to work, I don't remember.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Turns out it was an issue with compression! I removed that line from `server.js` and it worked like a charm!